# Mongo/Morphia too many connections Exception

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have created a singleton class to get the mongo datastore.

```
public enum AppMongoConfig {
    INSTANCE;
    private Mongo mongo;
    private Morphia morphia = new Morphia();;
    private Datastore datastore;
    private String ip;
    private String schema;
    private DB db;
    private int port;

    private AppMongoConfig() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        Logger.info(" ##### Initializing mongo app db ######");
        this.ip = Play.application().configuration()
                .getString("appMongoDBHost");
        this.schema = Play.application().configuration()
                .getString("appMongoDBSchema");
        this.port = Play.application().configuration().getInt("appMongoDBPort");
        try {
            this.mongo = new Mongo(this.ip, this.port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        this.db = this.mongo.getDB(this.schema);
        System.out.println(db.getCollection("DataSet").find().count());
        this.datastore = this.morphia.createDatastore(this.mongo,
                this.db.getName());
        Logger.info(" ##### Initialized mongo app db ######");
    }

    public Datastore getDs() {
        return this.datastore;
    }

}
```

Now i am calling getDs() on any method in my subsequent calls to query mongo database.Query includes find,update,save etc.
To view the stats of my mongoDB i executed the mongostats script.
I am constantly monitoring the no of active connections.
I see that active connection counts are increasing while my application is querying mongoDB.
This count is exceeding afterwhile and i have to restart my mongoDB.
Is there way to release the connection after some idletime or implement a connection pool so that mongo doesn't throw too many connections Exception?

Comment: Please show us your code where you are doing your find/update/saves. You might have a connection leak.

Comment: Is there a reason the initialize() method is public? If this is being called more than once, it could be causing your problem.